# Regular expression capture

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture

```
Client MAC:[C8:E0:EB:17:36:FF]
```

with

```
\bClient\s+MAC:[([0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2})]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` and `]` have special meaning and you should escape them when you want them to be matched literally:

```
\bClient\s+MAC:\[([0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2})\]
```